# Could CRA consider income from frequent trading of listed stock options as regular income, not capital gains?

Tags: income-tax, canada, trading, capital-gains-tax

I trade options on U.S. stocks frequently, several times a month. The income has been taxed as capital gains.

I am quite worried that the CRA could turn around and say that I am operating a business and tax the capital gains as ordinary income instead.

How likely is that?

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you have this fear?  Like a CRA document on the topic or maybe a news article?

Comment: [Looks like you may need to talk to a financial professional](http://turbotax.intuit.ca/tax-resources/tax-investment/how-to-calculate-capital-gains-when-day-trading-in-canada.jsp)

Comment: Depends on how much money you made, the frequency of the capital gain. As far as I know the CRA can't consider earning from futures trading income. But there are definitely exceptions, especially if you have the earning in a tax sheltered account.